# I am trying to run cross validation on the below, but am getting the following error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

This is what I have I am trying to use RELU, softmax and cross validation to help predict the trip type (y) from the x (weekday, upc, scancount, departmentdescription, and finelinenumber).

the data is coming from the Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/c/walmart-recruiting-trip-type-classification

```
>>import requests
>>df = ('Documents/train.csv')
>>DataLabels = ["Trip_Type", "Visit_Number", "Weekday", "UPC", "Scan_Count", 
    "Department_Description", "Fine_Line_number" ] 
>>data = pd.read_csv(df, header=None, names=DataLabels)

>>Weekday_mapping = {
       'Monday': (0),
       'Tuesday': (1),
       'Wednesday': (2),
       'Thursday': (3),
       'Friday': (4),
       'Saturday': (5),
       'Sunday': (6)
         }

>>data['Weekday'] = data['Weekday'].map(Weekday_mapping)
>>data


>>x=data.Weekday, data.UPC, data.Scan_Count, data.Department_Description, 
    data.Fine_Line_number
>>y=data.Trip_Type
>>X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, 
    random_state = 0)    


ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5, 647054]
```

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20199/train-test-split-error-found-input-variables-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-sam

Comment: @zoran119 thank you this is easier for me to understand than the other answers I have found.